# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'getCellPosition' of undefined' with Infinite scroll

Tags: ag-grid

I'm implementing Infinite scroll with Ag-Grid and found out that it’s throwing errors when scrolling at the below bottom of the grid data with cursor keys. Before new data is fetched from server, these errors are being produced:

```
Cannot read property 'getCellPosition' of undefined
```

You can reproduce the problem in the official plunker - [forked here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Xo98jAN7eupnrEjt)

To reproduce, just use hold down arrow-down key and check console after new data partition is fetched.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: cannot reproduce

Comment: Firefox throws different error - ERROR RowRenderer</RowRenderer.prototype.navigateToNextCell@https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@21.2.1/dist/ag-grid-community.js:13303:9

Comment: @un.spike just tested in Chrome on my Ubuntu and I can see the errors in the console. Could you please share the browser and OS you use where the link provided works? Thanks!

Comment: @un.spike this is what I am seeing -> https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/436605/67410647-ef07f680-f5ab-11e9-933e-b12b55180516.png

Answer (score 0):

even i got same issue, it is appearing only in case of server side pagination. I am not able understand to root cause but through some debugging, i have found below solution

I provided navigateToNextCell to grid options such that if rowCount in grid is equal to parameter rowCount i have returned null,

```
navigateToNextCell: (params) => {
  if (params.event.key==='ArrowDown') {
    if (this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() - 1 === params.nextCellPosition.rowIndex){
         return null;
    }
  }
  return params.nextCellPosition;
}
```

If you have any alternative solution please let me know.